# como estilizar um icon dentro input no React-native

Tags: react, react-native, android-styles

```ReactNative-js
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
//import { useNavigation }from '@react-navigation/native'
import {
  Octicons,
  Fontisto
} from '@expo/vector-icons'

import logoImg from '../../asserts/logo.png'

import styles from './style'
import {
  TextInput
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
export default function Welcome() {
  return ( <
    View style = {
      styles.container
    } >
    <
    View style = {
      styles.header
    } >
    <
    Image source = {
      logoImg
    }
    /> < /
    View >

    <
    View style = {
      styles.busca
    } >
    <
    Octicons name = 'three-bars'
    style = {
      styles.bars
    }
    /> <
    TextInput style = {
      styles.input
    } > Buscar <
    Fontisto name = 'mic'
    style = {
      styles.mic
    }
    /> < /
    TextInput > <
    /View>

    <
    /View>
  );
}
```

```css-js
import {
  StyleSheet
}

from 'react-native' export default StyleSheet.create( {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff', flex: 1,
  }
  , header: {
    marginTop: 30, marginBottom:30,
  }
  , busca: {
    flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'space-between'
  }
  , bars: {
    fontSize: 40, color:'grey', marginTop:2, marginLeft:15, marginRight:20
  }
  , input: {
    borderWidth: 1.7, width:250, height:45, fontSize:30, color:'#bebebe', fontWeight:'700', borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft:90, marginRight:30, borderColor:'#bebebe',
  }
  , mic: {
    fontSize: 30, color:'gray',
  }
}

)
```

[image: não estou conseguindo fazer que o icon mic fica separado da palavra buscar.]

> não estou conseguindo colocar o icon mic no final do imput e a palavras buscar no começo do imput os dois só se movem juntos ja tentei com flex,alignitems,justifyconten e nada fora as margin e paddding que moves o input ou os dois juntos queria passa uma estilização para cada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, o style "busca" está correto, quando você define uma direction como "row" e define o alinhamento como "space-between", se você tiver dois elementos, o primeiro vai para a esquerda, o segundo vai para a direita.

Existe duas formas de chegar neste resultado. A primeira seria mudar a ordem dos elementos. A segunda seria usar um componente que tenha um input com icone a esquerda ou direita.

O primeiro exemplo (mudando a ordem dos elementos) seria assim:

```
render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput style={{flex:1}} placeholder="Buscar" underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
            <Image source={require('./Images/ic_person.png')} style={styles.ImageStyle} />
        </View>
    </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },

  SectionStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: .5,
    borderColor: '#000',
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 5 ,
    margin: 10
},

ImageStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    margin: 5,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    resizeMode : 'stretch',
},
});
```

Caso você queira evitar este trabalho, ou o resultado ainda não tenha ficado de acordo com sua expectativa, você pode tentar usar este componente:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-textinput-with-icons

Exemplo de utilização:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TextInput from 'react-native-textinput-with-icons'

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    name: ''
  }

  render() {
    let { name } = this.state

    return (
      <TextInput
        label="Name"
        // RTL must used when label in arabic ex: label="اللغة العربيه"
        leftIcon="thumbsup"
        leftIconType="oct"
        rippleColor="blue"
        rightIcon="react"
        rightIconType="material"
        value={name}
        refrance={(refrance) => {
            this.input = refrance;
        }}
        onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Aqui tem alguns tutoriais que podem te ajudar:
Exemplos de textbox com ícones:
https://aboutreact.com/image-icon-with-react-native-textinput/
https://reactnativecode.com/place-image-icon-inside-textinput-left-side/

Alinhamento com Flexbox:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: conseguir coloquei um view antes do input e coloquei a mesma estlização do flexdirection; 'row' e coloquei justifcontent : 'space between' ,ai só formatei o tamanho e o bordecolor